# SQL - Count two columns together

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to count multiple columns as one column. For example:

Table 1 (Books):

| ID | BookName | Genre | SubGenre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Name2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Name3 | 4 | 2 |

Table 2 (Genre):

| ID | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Horror |
| 2 | Drama |
| 3 | Romance |
| 4 | Sci-Fi |

I want to be able to count the genre and subgenre as one to create a table of:

Result:

| Genre | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Horror | 2 |
| Drama | 2 |
| Romance | 1 |
| Sci-Fi | 1 |

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How count is 2 for Horror? What is logic behind it?

Comment: Because Horror is a Genre of Book1 and a SubGenre of Book2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query-

```
SELECT t.Genre, Sum(t.cg) AS Count
FROM (

SELECT t2.Genre, Count(t1.Genre) AS cg
FROM Table2 as t2 LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1 ON t2.ID = t1.Genre
GROUP BY t2.Genre

UNION ALL 

SELECT t2.Genre, Count(t1.SubGenre) AS cg
FROM Table2 as t2 LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1 ON t2.ID = t1.SubGenre
GROUP BY t2.Genre

) as t GROUP BY t.Genre;
```

[image]